# How to add Gunicorn to Django app running in docker?

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a django app running with a docker in a Digitalocean droplet.

My question is, where do I add the `gunicorn.socket` and the `gunicorn.service`? In the Django Docker app or in the DigitalOcean running the docker?

`gunicorn.socket is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and `gunicorn.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.asgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```